# How possible is using complex variables to model the electric field system of a dipole?

Tags: electric-fields, mathematical-physics, complex-numbers, dipole, dipole-moment

If one considera a dipole system, is it possible to model the system using complex variables and if ao, how can we use complex analysis to model it? I have the idea that we can model dipole moment as a complex variable and then use a line integral to determine the potential energy at any point in the system. However,I am quite unsure.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594302/2451

Comment: Hi Donna Paul. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Why do you want to unnecessarily complicate a dipole field by using complex variables? It is easily described without them.

Comment: I'm doing  a course in which we study complex analysis and its application to Physics. This is a question on my assignment and I also think it would be more complicated, but I just want to know if its possible and if so, how?